# Datatype date is not updating in mysql using laravel

Tags: php, mysql, date, laravel-8

A column named 'Shipment' in import_request_trackers table having the datatype of Date and initially the default value is null.

```
$table->date('Shipment')->nullable();
$table->date('Arrival')->nullable();
```

But when I tried to update the column from another form manually it shows no error but the database table is not being updated.

```
public function shipmentadd(Request $request, $id){
    $tracker = ImportRequestTracker::where('OrderNo', $id)->first();

   $inputs = [
      'Shipment' => $request->input('ShipmentDate')
    ];
          
    $tracker->update($inputs);
    return redirect()->route('developer.import.tracker');
```

}

Comment: can you add the output of `dd($tracker)`

Comment: The issue is solved now. Following the code structure of calling update directly. There was an issue with the first() function which I used to fetch the data. Trying to find out the issue now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**1-** check your route first, please note that your **`$id`** is passing correctly!

**2-** check the data, you may use "`dd($id , $request->input('ShipmentDate'))` to check it.

**3-** please note that your ShipmentDate data should have a certain structure like: `2022-12-01 or 2022/12/01 (Y-m-d or Y/m/d) and etc.`
As a string in either '`YYYY-MM-DD`' or '`YY-MM-DD`' format. A “relaxed” syntax is permitted: Any punctuation character may be used as the delimiter between date parts. For example, `'2012-12-31', '2012/12/31', '2012^12^31', and '2012@12@31'` are equivalent.
As a string with no delimiters in either 'YYYYMMDD' or 'YYMMDD' format, provided that the string makes sense as a date. For example, '20070523' and '070523' are interpreted as '2007-05-23', but '071332' is illegal (it has nonsensical month and day parts) and becomes '0000-00-00'.

As a number in either `YYYYMMDD` or `YYMMDD` format, provided that the number makes sense as a date. For example, `19830905` and `830905` are interpreted as `'1983-09-05'`.

all in all, after cheking the data you may use this code:

```
public function shipmentadd(Request $request, $id){
    $tracker = ImportRequestTracker::where('OrderNo', $id)->update([
      'Shipment' => $request->input('ShipmentDate'),
   ]);
       
    return redirect()->route('developer.import.tracker');

}
```

Comment: Thanks. But 1,2,3 points all were okay in my code. No error found. But still the data was not being updated in database.

But your code structure worked. Might be an issue was there in the first() function which I used to fetch the data.